# Limit $\lim _{n \to \infty} \frac {\sqrt[2n] {(2n-1)!!}} {\sqrt [n^2] a_n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, infinite-product

Let us consider the sequence $(a_n)_{n \ge 1}$ defined as follows: $a_1 = 1$ and $a_{n+1}=(2n+1)!! a_n, \forall n \ge 1$. I had to compute the limit:
$$\lim _{n \to \infty} \frac {\sqrt[2n] {(2n-1)!!}} {\sqrt [n^2] a_n}$$
that Jack D'Aurizio's solution below shows to be $e^{1/4}$ through Riemann sums.
I am wondering about different/simpler approaches: is it possible to tackle such limit through the [Stoltz-Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem), for instance?

Comment: You're not new here, you know you're supposed to give a bit more context than just a problem statement copied and pasted.

Comment: @M. Stefan: now that my answer has an extended explanation here (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2187546/interesting-limit-with-log-function?noredirect=1&lq=1), I suggest to improve this question in the following way: by mentioning the solution through Riemann sums and asking for different/simpler solutions. It is an interesting problem, it is a pity it is put *on hold*, let us try to restore it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>This is the original approach through Riemann sums, with an extended explanation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2187546/interesting-limit-with-log-function?noredirect=1&lq=1).</sup>

$$ a_n = \prod_{k=1}^{n}(2k-1)^{n+1-k} \tag{1}$$
leads to
$$ \frac{1}{n^2}\log a_n = \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(n+1-k)\log(2k-1) \tag{2}$$
and to:
$$ \frac{1}{2n}\log(2n-1)!! = \frac{1}{2n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log(2k-1) \tag{3} $$
hence $(2)-(3)$ equals
$$ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left[\frac{k+1}{n}-\frac{1}{2}\right]\log(2n-2k-1) \tag{4}$$
that for large values of $n$ converges to
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)\log(2-2x)\,dx=-\frac{1}{4}.\tag{5} $$
The given limit is so $\color{red}{\large e^{1/4}}.$